# What does "INSERT 0 1" mean after executing direct SQL in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

When I execute a file containing SQL commands with `psql -f`, I get output like this (truncated):

```
CREATE DOMAIN
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
```

What do the numbers 0 and 1 mean? (I think 1 is the number of rows modified. But 0?) I can't find it in [PostgreSQL's official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) or anywhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is documented with the [INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.7) command

> On successful completion, an INSERT command returns a command tag of the form
>
> ```
> INSERT oid count
> ```
>
> The count is the number of rows inserted or updated. oid is always 0 (it used to be the OID assigned to the inserted row if count was exactly one and the target table was declared WITH OIDS and 0 otherwise, but creating a table WITH OIDS is not supported anymore).

Comment: Ah, a link just to the right place! I looked at the (long) "INSERT" article but couldn't see it. Thanks!